# Android: android:layout_width=wrap_content but not less than X dp?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, android-layout, android-gui

Is it possible to define GUI element width as `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` but somehow define minimal width of `Xdp`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the attribute you are looking for is `android:minWidth`. For example,

```
android:minWidth="10dp"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

```
android:minHeight="20dp"
android:minWidth="20dp"
```

in your xml layout

`20dp` is a sample value